# e.preventDefault(); is not working on imported custom button component react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am building a form and I imported a custom Button component with an onCLick. In my handleClick function I added `e.preventDefault` as I wanted to see if the inputs from the form worked. It worked fine yesterday when I just used a normal button, but its not working after adding the Button component. Please what am I missing here?

```js
import React from 'react';
import PageContainer from '../../layout/page-container/PageContainer';
import newlogin from './newlogin.scss'
import Button from '../../components/button/Button';


class NewInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
    
  }

  handleName = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState ({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  }


  handleEmail = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState ({
    email: e.target.value
     // [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handlePassword = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState ({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  }
 
  
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    
    console.log('Submitting');
    console.log(this.state);
    
  }

  render(){
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    return (
      <PageContainer title="Login">
          
      <form>
        <input name='name' type='text' placeholder='Enter your name' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleName} />   
        <input name='email' type='text' placeholder='Enter your email' value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmail} />
        <input name='password' type='password' placeholder='Enter your password' value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePassword}/>
        <Button size='small'  color='warning' onClick={this.handleSubmit (e.preventDefault())}>Login</Button>
      </form>
      <p>Your email is: {this.state.email}</p>
      </PageContainer>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

type Props = {
  children: any,
  type?: string,
  size?: string,
  color?: string,
  outline?: string
}

const Button = (props:Props) => {

  let btnClass = ''

    if(props.type === 'full') btnClass = 'full ';
    if(props.type === 'inline') btnClass = 'inline ';
    if(props.type === 'block') btnClass = 'block '
    
    if(props.size === 'small') btnClass += 'small ';
    if(props.size === 'large') btnClass += 'large ';

    if(props.color === 'primary') btnClass += 'primary '
    if(props.color === 'warning') btnClass += 'warning '
    if(props.color === 'info') btnClass += 'info '

    if(props.outline === 'transparent') btnClass += ' transparent'
    

  return (
    <button className={btnClass} > {props.children}</button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: Would like to see the code for your button component

Comment: trying to add it to the original post but no luck.

Comment: i think that is where your issue is. So if you can add it, will gladly help

Answer (score 2):

preventDefault in handleSubmit:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault() // preventDefault here
    console.log('Submitting');
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

Call handleSubmit in Button:

```
onClick={this.handleSubmit}
```

---

**Edit, pass props into Button like this**

```
type Props = {
  children: any,
  type?: string,
  size?: string,
  color?: string,
  outline?: string,
  onClick?: any // define onClick in Props Type
}
const Button = (props:Props) => {
  let btnClass = "";
  ...
  ...
  return (
    <button className={btnClass} {...props}> // here
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I just did but it still not working. the page still refreshes.

Comment: trying to add it to the original post but its not working.

Comment: its added now @jdn

Comment: Amazing!! I understand what you did there.. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not a passing the handler to the button, you are calling it passing the return value. It has to be just:

```
<Button size='small'  color='warning' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Login</Button>
```

Then use `preventDefault()` **inside** of the handler:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('Submitting');
  console.log(this.state);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I already tried that and its not working. I also tried the above way of implementing the button component but it does not give me the right button values that I pass in my code.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, the `form` submit event will be fired which will refresh the page by default, so you have to hook in to the `onSubmit` method of the `form` and call the `preventDefault` there, in order to fire the submit event on the button click you have to set `type="submit"` on the `Button` component.

Make your `handleSubmit` function like:

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Submitting');
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

and in your form use it like:

```
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        // ...
        // Input fields
        // ...


        <Button type="submit" size="small"  color="warning">Login</Button>
    </form>
```

Make sure that the `Button` component passes through the `type` prop.

```
const Button = ({ children, ...props }) => (
   <button {...props}>{children}</button>
)
```

Comment: but this makes the whole from area submitting - I only want it on the button.

Comment: I understand, then I suggest to create a separate `onSubmit` handler for the form with an `e.preventDefault()` call and a seperate handler with the actual submitting logic that you add to the Button onClick

Comment: Hi, I manage to figure it out. I had to update my button component by adding the right props. Thanks for the help!